# Is it possible to attach multiple images in a embed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm setting up a waifu gacha game in `discord.js` and wondering if its possible to send a embed with multiple images? In the same matter as this

(https://pm1.narvii.com/7022/e92995beeea9d48d4344c7fcdd97bedbf3fd4d13r1-1920-1080v2_hq.jpg)

Here's my embed code if needed:

```
    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * animechr.characters.length);
    oof = animechr.characters[number]["name"]
    oof2 = animechr.characters[number]["image_url"]
    const waifu = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(anime.title)
    .setThumbnail(oof2)
    .setTitle(oof)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Pulled time:')
    message.channel.sendEmbed(waifu)
```

Though I have no clue how to achieve this I really have no basis on anything except `.setImage` and `.setThumbnail`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is actually a way. Webhook messages can contain up to 10 embeds per message. So you can, using a webhook, send 10 embeds, each of them containing one images.

The image are supposed to have width and height fields [documented here](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#embed-object-embed-image-structure) but I didn't see any way with embed object or RichEmbed to do it, so you'll have to resize the images you want to use so they are of the same size.

In your case, the idea of slothiful: merging the image in one canvas and rendering it, would be a better and closer to the picture you shared

```js
const client = new Discord.Client();
const hook = new Discord.WebhookClient(webHook.id, webHook.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('Starting!');
  client.user.setActivity(config.activity);
});



client.on('message', async (msg) => {
  if (msg.author.bot) { return; }
  sendImage();
});

let webHook = {
  token: "token-webhook",
  id: "id-webhook"
};

let img = [
  'https://i.imgur.com/ezC66kZ.png',
  'https://i.imgur.com/wSTFkRM.png'
];

function sendImage() {
  let embeds = [];
  embeds.push(new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle('First Messages')
          .setImage(img[0])
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter('Pulled time:'));
  embeds.push(new Discord.RichEmbed()
          .setTitle('First Messages')
          .setImage(img[1])
          .setTimestamp()
          .setFooter('Pulled time:'));
  hook.send({embeds: embeds});
}

client.login(config.token)
  .then(() => console.log("We're in!"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Render:
[image]

Comment: when coding a bot anyway... why using webook? you can simply create an embed array as you did and write it to the channel you want.

Comment: @dwza I was actually searching for a way to send it at once in one embed. The webhook was the only instructions to send multiple embed at once. One advantage being, normally, not being rate limited. But yeah, multiple send is possible normally. I think I only found that, and used it this way without thinking more

Answer (score 7):

I found [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/raz4kl/finally_a_way_to_display_multiple_images_in_an/) which shows that the client aggregates embeds that are part of the same message, as long as the URL property is the exact same.
In order for the title and other props to show up, they need to be set on the first embed.
Beware however that setting a URL property will also make the embed title link to whatever URL was set.
Also note that the mobile app discards all but the first embed.

```js
const embeds = [
    new EmbedBuilder().setURL("https://example.org/").setImage("https://picsum.photos/500/500")
        .setTitle("title").setDescription("desc").setFooter({ text: "footer" }),
    new EmbedBuilder().setURL("https://example.org/").setImage("https://picsum.photos/500/400"),
    new EmbedBuilder().setURL("https://example.org/").setImage("https://picsum.photos/400/500"),
    new EmbedBuilder().setURL("https://example.org/").setImage("https://picsum.photos/400/400"),
];

await interaction.reply({ embeds });
```

[image: showcase]

Comment: Do you have an implementation of this in elixir using Nostrum?

Comment: doesnt work on mobile. it disappears.

Comment: I haven't tested this with the new mobile app but on the old one (which you can reenable with some scripts you can find online) it would only show the first image.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no.

You can use both the image and thumbnail properties of the embed, but that limits you to two images, both being displayed differently. You could attach files to the message, but they would be shown separately from the embed.

My suggestion would be to load multiple images together with [`canvas`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas), save the canvas as a PNG, and set it as the embed's image. It would essentially be a collage of the images, allowing you to display all of them in the embed.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add small images next to some content if you need to. See the code here. Both the .setAuthor and .setFooter properties use very tiny images on the Embed.

```
const myEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor('#0099ff')
    .setTitle('Add Jerseyetr')
    .setURL('https://steamcommunity.com/id/jerseyetr')
    .setAuthor('Midnight Bot', 'IMAGE FILE HERE', 'censored')
    .setDescription('')
    .setThumbnail('IMAGE FILE HERE')
    .addField('How to Gain Access to the Server', '1. Go to the Rules Section and read the rules \n2. Add Jerseyetr on Steam. Link above \n3. Download and install our mods. Check the #information Channel for info')
    .addBlankField()
    .addField('Mods download:', 'censored', true)
    .addField('how to install mods', 'censored', true)
    .addField('Vote for our Server', 'censored', true)
    .setImage('IMAGE FILE HERE')
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Updated 5/20', 'IMAGE FILE HERE');

channel.send(myEmbed);
```

The .setAuthor property contains a small thumbnail